# how to send email quickly in PHP using phpmailer

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am using phpmailer to send email with SMTP in php. It is taking around 2 to 3 seconds to send the email. To send it quicker I should use php mail function which I don't want. As I am using phpmailer, can I get any suggestion to send it quickly using phpmailer and sending directly to the destination smtp server instead of going through the local SMTP and then MTA and to the destination SMTP server.

Comment: I think your bottleneck is on the SMTP server and not on PHP.

Comment: you can configure phpMailer to use the `mail()` function internally rather than SMTP if you want to. It can also use POP3.